# NullException appears when the page is opened in ASP MVC

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I am developing an ASP.Net MVC 3 application using C# and SQL Server 2005.

I have created a button which will appear a fieldset when it will be clicked on (and that using a Jquery affect slide down).

The fieldset contain a form.

When I have created a DropDownList i this form,,,I have called a list from a FormViewModel (because i am using Entity Framework and Code First approach).

the problem is : when i open the page, this exception appears :

```
NullReferenceException was unhadled by user code. Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

It's related to the 'PostesItems', I don't know why he demand a declaration of the object because i import it from the viewModel.

This is the code of the view :

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MvcApplication2.Models.FlowViewModel>" %>




<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>
    <fieldset class="parametrage">
        <legend>Gestion de Gamme</legend>

        <div><%:Html.Label("Poste :")%><%: Html.DropDownList("SelectedPoste", new SelectList(Model.PostesItems, "ID_Poste", "ID_Poste"))%></div>


         <div><%:Html.Label("Nombre de Passage :")%><%: Html.DropDownList("SelectedGamme", new SelectList(Model.GaItems,"Nbr_Passage","Nbr_Passage") )%></div>




        </fieldset>
         <% } %>
```

and this the FlowViewModel which I called :

```
namespace MvcApplication2.Models
{
    public class FlowViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public string IDv { get; set; }
        public List<Poste> PostesItems { get; set; }
        public List<Profile_Ga> Profile_GaItems { get; set; }
        public List<Gamme> GaItems { get; set; }

        public int SelectedProfile_Ga { get; set; }

        public int SelectedGamme{ get; set; }

        public int SelectedPoste { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and this the controller which show the view :

```
private GammeContext db = new GammeContext();

        //
        // GET: /ProfileGa/
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index(Profile_Ga profile_ga, Poste poste)
        {

            var viewModel = new FlowViewModel();
            viewModel.PostesItems = db.Postes.ToList();
               viewModel.Profile_GaItems = db.Profil_Gas.ToList();
               viewModel.GaItems = db.Gammes.ToList();
               return View(viewModel);



        }
```

this is the Poste Model :

```
namespace MvcApplication2.Models
{
    public class Poste
    {
        [Required]
        [Key]
        [Display(Name = "ID Poste :")]
        public string ID_Poste { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Nom Poste:")]
        public string nom_Poste { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Application :")]
        public string Application { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "In Poste :")]
        public string In_Po { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Out Poste :")]
        public string Out_Po { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Etat :")]
        public string Etat { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [ForeignKey("Ligne")]
        [Display(Name = "ID Ligne :")]
        public string ID_Ligne { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Mouvement :")]
        public string Mouvement { get; set; }

        public virtual Ligne Ligne { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Ligne> Lignes { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Poste> Postes { get; set; }
    }
```

and this the Gamme Model :

```
public class Gamme
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 0)]
        [ForeignKey("Profile_Ga")]
        public string ID_Gamme { get; set; }
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        [ForeignKey("Poste")]
        public string ID_Poste { get; set; }
        public int Position { get; set; }
        public int Nbr_Passage { get; set; }
        public string Last_Posts { get; set; }
        public string Next_Posts { get; set; }

        public virtual Poste Poste { get; set; }
        public virtual Profile_Ga Profile_Ga { get; set; }

    } }
```

the error :
[image: error]

Comment: How are you populating `PostesItems`?

Comment: Could you show controller action that returns this view?

Comment: I have a table Poste in my base,,,,using entity framework,,,it will be populated like a liste,,,look to my edit please,,,i will put the controller

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov sure,,,just look at my edit

Comment: Could you place breakpoint after viewModel.PostesItems = db.Postes.ToList(); and look what is in this property?

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov i put a breakpoint,,the execution is the same ,,,sorry but i didn't find how to look for the property?

Comment: You should start debugging (F5 in visual studio) In this case execution should stop on breakpoint.

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov I know I did that but nothing new

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29827/discussion-between-kirill-bestemyanov-and-anouar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Based on discussion in chat:**

In your Index view there is js function that loads content from another controller action.

You problem is in `AnnouarController`. Your method `Gestion()` returns View with model of type `FlowViewModel`, but model is not initialized.
You should change at least to:

```
         public ActionResult Gestion()
         {
               var viewModel = new FlowViewModel();
               viewModel.PostesItems = new SelectList(db.Postes.ToList(), "ID_Poste", "ID_Poste"); 
               return View(viewModel);
         }
```

Answer (score 2):

As error suggest your `PostesItems` are null. `EntityFramework` uses lazy loading approach which means that it won't load related entities if not ordered to do so.

One of way loading your posts is:

```
FlowViewModel model = db.FlowViews... // loading view model
model.PostesItems = db.PostesItems.ToList();
```

more info [about lazy loading here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)

Comment: thx for the answer,,,I guess I did that in my controller,,,can you take a look at my edit

Comment: I still stuck here, can you look that with me please?

Comment: I'm looking and I cant see anything wrong with your code. Is that your full html view code that you posted?

Comment: it's the full html code of the view which i want shown when the button is clicked

Comment: gzaxx - I would have thought ToList would cause immediate execution, turning that db.PostesItems into a list in the action, not in the view?

Comment: IMO that would not change anything. I'm looking and that code and I cant find anything wrong with it, sorry :/